# Is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>
> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server'

Почему вылазит эта ошибка?

Все права пользователю на удаленные подключения даны, через Mysql Workbrench нормально подключается.

Сервер XAMPP.

Comment: К какому хосту вы пытаетесь подключиться: к локальному или удалённому? Если к локальному, то попробуйте явно прописать `127.0.0.1` вместо `localhost` (если прописан `localhost`).

Comment: Прописал, все равно

Answer (score 1):

Причина ошибки в том, что у вас не прописаны или не активированы доступы к серверу с данного IP, на котором запускается скрипт.

Необходимо выполнить команду на сервере MariaDB:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseName.* TO 'username'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Подставив нужные значения (databaseName, username, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, password)  , после чего выполнить команду перезагрузки доступов:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Доступ должен появиться. Ничего больше делать не требуется.

Comment: Не помогло. Я же могу подключиться через WorkBrench с тем же логином

Comment: `select * from mysql.user where Host = 'ваш IP из ошибки' and User = 'ваш проблемный пользователь' \G` и вывод сюда